# My DynamoDB query throws an error 500 no connection could be made

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

```
public async Task<ReturnJsonResult<EzUser>> GetUser(string uID)
{
    QueryRequest req = new QueryRequest()
    {
        TableName = _tableInfo.UsersTable,
        KeyConditionExpression = "#nm = :val",
        ExpressionAttributeNames = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
            {"#nm", "uID"},
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>() {
            {":val", new AttributeValue() {
                S = uID
            }},
        },
    };

    var res = await _dynamoDb.QueryAsync(req);
}
```

Note: I have included the code upto the error, the function actually returns a JsonResult.
Note #2: This is an ASP.NET Core Application

While executing the QueryAsync, the program throws: ***Error: 500 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it***.

Things tested:

1. AWS Configuration is correct
2. Table exists
3. Table name and request is correct
4. Credentials and Dynamo queries work in another application running on the same computer

I am bamboozled.

Comment: Where are you specifying which host it should connect to for the request?

Comment: The AWSConfigs are done in Startup.cs

Comment: And how does `QueryRequest` and/or `_dynamoDb` know about those configurations?

Comment: Because the configurations are setup on Startup and the services are registered using services.Add, _dynamoDb is just the service from the interface IAmazonDynamoDB. There are no issues with the configuration. I have the same configuration running in several other applications.

Comment: If there was no issue with the configuration it would work, right?